# Strict transform of a family near the non-flat locus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Given a flat family $f: X \rightarrow B$ and some subscheme $S$ of $B$ I think it is in Hartshorne or Liu (but I do not have a copy to hand) that the strict transform of $X$ is then flat over the blow up of $B$ in $S$.

In general let $N$ be the locus inside $Y$ along which $f$ fails to be flat. Suppose that we choose a point $S$ on $N$ and blow up at this point. Can we say anything about the non-flat locus of the strict transform of $f$ inside the blow up of $Y$ at $S$? My intuition says that it is just the strict transform of $N$ but I can't see a reference anywhere.